# I'm stuck somewhere in Excel where I need help creating an if formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, data-analysis

I want a formula that, if the first or second cell is similar to the third, return 1, and if not, return 0, and if the cell is empty, return 0[image]

I tried this formula and it was correct to some extent, but the only thing I want is that it returns 0 in the following empty or blank cells as well.

Comment: too many edit on the first comment: `=IF(AND(C2<>"",OR(EXACT(A2,C2),EXACT(B2,C2))),1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Formula

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1="",B1=""),C1=""),0,IF(OR(A1=C1,B1=C1),1,0))
```